# How to find out which context reaction is firing?

Tags: views, 7, theming

im creating some pages that have specific layouts for tablets and mobiles, to send a targeted view and template im using context, context breakpoints and delta.

But i need some way of seeing which context reaction s being fired as on some pages an endless auto-reload is occurring, i think it might be due to some paths having multiple reactions, so im looking for some way to see which reaction is being fired and getting buggy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn on context debug under context settings (*admin/structure/context/settings*) - checkbox 'Enable debug reaction on all contexts'.

It will output debug messages for every event, condition, and reaction. This could help you determine what keeps reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

About a year ago I was working on a project where the breakpoints module would periodically send us into refresh loops.  I don't remember the particulars - only that the issue was due to the cookies not being cleared properly.

Breakpoints relies heavily on cookies to determine which display to use and when the cookies aren't cleared the module receives somewhat mixed messages.  I use Chrome for my development and found the extension [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en) very helpful.

Comment: Yes i guessed it a cookie getting stuck somewhere, i just experienced the error came back here to look at the answers, then went to go debug and it disappears again, but next time i will be ready!!!